# file_get_content different output than actual source code

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Why doesn't

```
$txt = file_get_contents('https://www.cloudflare.com/system-status.html');
```

get the correct source code of https://www.cloudflare.com/system-status.html

`file_get_contents <div class="article">` output:

```
<div class="article">
<div id="cfstatus-table-wrapper" style="display: none;">
<table id="cfstatus-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="cfstatus-table-location"></th>

<th class="cfstatus-table-current">Current status</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-0">Sep 8</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-1">Sep 7</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-2">Sep 6</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-3">Sep 5</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-4">Sep 4</th>
<th class="cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn" id="cfstatus-table-history-5">Sep 3</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="cfstatus-table-corners"><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-tl"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-tr"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-br"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-bl"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

actual `<div class="article">` output:

```
<div class="article">
                                <div id="cfstatus-table-wrapper" style="">
                                    <table id="cfstatus-table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-location"></th>
                                                <!-- -->
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-current">Current status</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-0">Mar 17</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-1">Mar 16</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-2">Mar 15</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-3">Mar 14</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history" id="cfstatus-table-history-4">Mar 13</th>
                                                <th class="cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn" id="cfstatus-table-history-5">Mar 12</th>
                                                <!-- -->
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody><tr id="cfstatus-table-cf"><th class="cfstatus-table-location" id="cfstatus-table-location-cf">CloudFlare System</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr>

                                        <tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Amsterdam, NL</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="performance-degradation cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Performance degradation</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Ashburn, VA</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Chicago, IL</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Dallas, TX</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="status-report cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Status report</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Frankfurt, DE</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Hong Kong, HK</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">London, GB</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="status-report cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Status report</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Los Angeles, CA</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="performance-degradation cfstatus-table-history" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Performance degradation</span></td><td class="performance-degradation cfstatus-table-history" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Performance degradation</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Miami, FL</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Newark, NJ</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Paris, FR</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">San Jose, CA</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="performance-degradation cfstatus-table-history" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Performance degradation</span></td><td class="performance-degradation cfstatus-table-history" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Performance degradation</span></td><td class="status-report cfstatus-table-history" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; "><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Status report</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Singapore, SG</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr><tr><th class="cfstatus-table-location">Tokyo, JP</th><td class="online cfstatus-table-current"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td><td class="online cfstatus-table-history cfstatus-table-lastColumn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="label">Online</span></td></tr></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div id="cfstatus-table-corners"><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-tl"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-tr"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-br"></div><div id="cfstatus-table-corner-bl"></div></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I don't know why this is happening; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is not static HTML but is build by JavaScript on page load.

You could use [their JSON API at `https://www.cloudflare.com/ajax/sys-status.html`](https://www.cloudflare.com/ajax/sys-status.html) instead and do the same for your site. But ask them for permission first.